# Link Error With Visual Studio 2005 Using Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors, winapi

I am in the process of evaluating an upgrade to Windows SDK 7.1

Part of my team's legacy codebase is a large number of ATL web services, which are still maintained using Visual Studio 2005 because (I am told) ATL web services are not supported in versions beyond 2005.

When I pointed the IDE to SDK 7.1, I began to receive the following link error:

```
uuid.lib(cguid_i.obj) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module
```

I haven't been able to find much on the web related to this problem in VS2005 and SDK 7.1.
I found some [forum posts](http://www.coderedgames.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=25) from back in 2005 about the same error -- they seemed to indicate an SDK incompatibility.

Based on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en#Requirements), I was under the impression that Windows SDK 7.1 could be used with Visual Studio 2005 (although I do note the "Not all features work with all versions of Visual Studio" disclaimer).

Is this a known issue, or have I got something configured incorrectly?

I was hoping someone could share their experience or suggest how/if I might be able to resolve this.

EDIT:
I discovered that this problem is circumvented by disabling /DEBUG on the linker command line. While allowing the build to complete, this is suboptimal as it precludes debugging during future maintenance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hotfix listed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949009) appears to address the link error. Not sure how I missed it before.

Including here in case anyone ever searches for it using similar language.